# Command line tool to generate C# .Net Framework client for an Open API specification. Note: It is not for C# .Net Core

Tags: c#, rest, http

Are there any command line tools available, using which one can generate HTTP proxy client in C# .Net Framework for an Open API? We have WSDL.exe with similar provision for SOAP based Web Service. What is the equivalent for RESTful Web Service that is generally used?

Comment: Connected Services or OData client if your service is compliant.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSchaller! This is helpful. I could install the extension in Visual Studio 2019, and generate the client code for the REST service. I am checking of ways to do the same in command prompt. I am working on code generator part of a module in our product, where it generates C# files, compiles them using csc.exe. One task we have is to generate client code for REST service, and this generator is triggered command line.